# typescript extends Array, built-in methods whose return type is `this` cannot return `SubArray`

Tags: typescript

I am createing my `MyArray` class extending `Array<number>`.

With built-in methods, the return type is not `MyArray`(eg: `slice` return type is `number[]`), while returning `this` on purpose works well(eg: `insert` return type is `MyArray`). How can I make built-in methods whose return type is `this` return `MyArray`?

```js
class MyArray extends Array<number> {
    constructor(...items: number[]) {
        super(...items);
    }

    insert(num: number): this {
        return this;
    }
}

const myArray = new MyArray(1, 2, 3);
const secondArray = myArray.slice(0, 3); // Here is number[], whereas I want it to be `MyArray` type
const thirdArray = myArray.insert(3); // with returning `this` on purpose, it's ok
```

Here's [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRB2Yw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

nevermind, the property of the functions you are asking for is called [Polymorphic this types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types). And in that case its totally correct that `slice` returns an `number[]` instead of `MyArray`, that is because slice does infact not mutate the array but returns a copy of the array, and because the standard implementation doesn't know about `MyArray` it will return `number[]`. If you want to change this you will need to provide your own implementation of slice which does infact return an `MyArray` instance like so:

```
class MyArray extends Array<number> {
    constructor(...items: number[]) {
        super(...items);
    }

    insert(num: number): this {
        return this;
    }

    slice(start?: number | undefined, end?: number | undefined): MyArray {
        return new MyArray(...[...this].slice(start,end));
    }
}
```

please note that you cannot declare slice as `slice (...):this` because `Array.slice` isn't mutating and produces a new array.

old answer:

Afaik, you will have to re-declare all the functions you want to use, to return `MyArray`s:

```
class MyArray extends Array<number> {
    constructor(...items: number[]) {
        super(...items);
    }

    insert(num: number): this {
        return this;
    }

    declare slice: (start?: number | undefined, end?: number | undefined) => this
}
```

Comment: If you take a look at a mutating function such as `sort` you would see that it returns `MyArray`

Comment: Instead of `[...this].slice` you can use `Array.protype.slice.call(this, ...)` to avoid an extra copy

Comment: @dsalex1 Seems like `declare` approach is simpler, cause I won't change the implementation detail, just want `slice` returning `this` for later fluent API usage.

Comment: @crazyones110 you cant really do that, because you wont have an instance of `MyArray` at runtime, so trying to use any `MyArray` specific functions such as insert will throw an error at runtime, you need to provide your own implementation. infebore, the slice default implementation *does not* return `this`