# Javascript overidden filter method strange behavior

Tags: javascript

I tried to implement `MyArray` extending built-in Array, and overrode `filter`. Weird things happened when I was trying to filter `MyArray`, the constructor was called and `nums` is `[0]`

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  constructor(...nums) {
    super(...nums);
    this.tmpStore = {}; // for distinguishing purpose
    if (nums.length === 1) {
      this.length = 0;
      console.log("where did \`[0]\` suddenly jump out from??", nums, nums[0]); // here `nums` is [0]
      Array.prototype.push.call(this, nums[0]);
    }
  }
  
  filter(predicate) {
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(this, predicate);
  }
}

const myArray = new MyArray(100, 200);
const filterRes = myArray.filter(num => num === "nonsense");
console.log("filterRes", filterRes); // expect filterRes to be `[]`
```

The correct way to implement `filter` may be `[...this].filter(predicate)`, but it will bring an extra copy, and I wonder the root reason.

maybe [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75755630/typescript-extends-array-built-in-methods-whose-return-type-is-this-cannot-re#comment133637919_75755876)

Comment: as for the strange `filter` behaviour, you should look into the way in which `filter` creates the copy on which it will operate; it looks like it is interacting badly with your extended constructor. see [spec: Array.prototype.filter](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.filter) and [ArraySpeciesCreate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-arrayspeciescreate)

Comment: If you override fundamentals of the built-in constructor you can't expect the built-in methods to work

Comment: @pilchard sorry for the disorder, have edited the question

Comment: @crazyones110 So what you want to do is that `new MyArray(x)` creates an Array with the length `1` that has `x` as one element? So you change the behavior from setting the length of the Array to using it as an element. Such changes in an inheriting class  is itself not wrong, but you can't except that you can call `Array.prototype.filter.call` and that class as `filer` creates a new Array, which expects that the original Array constructors exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` always invokes `Array(0)`, no matter what (see https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.filter, item 4)

If `filter` does return results, this `0` gets overwritten later on, otherwise it stays there.

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
    constructor(...strs) {
        super()
        this.mark = 'hey'
        console.log('Myarray(' + JSON.stringify(strs) + ')')
        this.push(...strs)
    }
}

const myArray = new MyArray(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

r = myArray.filter(x => x > 4)
console.log(r)

r = myArray.filter(x => x > 100)
console.log(r)
```

You can hack around this behaviour by giving your class a "species", which returns an additional constructor which accepts length:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
    constructor(...strs) {
        super()
        this.mark = 'hey'
        console.log('Myarray(' + JSON.stringify(strs) + ')')
        this.push(...strs)
    }

    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return function (length) {
            return new MyArray()
        }
    }

}

const myArray = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

r = myArray.filter(x => x > 4)
console.log(r)

r = myArray.filter(x => x > 100)
console.log(r)
```

Whether it's worth the trouble, is up to you. Extending builtins is a bad idea mostly, if you need something "array-like", use delegation, not inheritance.

Comment: While I agree that inheriting form a built-in type is bad for most languages. It is especially bad if one way of constructing the inherited class is repurposed and not just extended.

Comment: What do you mean delegation? Something like `const myArray = { arr: [], mark: "hey" }`?

Comment: @crazyones110: exactly, and then define your methods like `filter() { return new MyArray(this.arr.filter(...))` etc.